# Gekko error 'Error: Cannot find module '../core/log.js''

Tags: javascript, terminal

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEPlk.png)

link to the output is above!!

not sure what im missing, new to gekko aswell. Looking for answers or advice !!! Thank you.

Comment: java is wrong tag. please incorporate code into your question  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Gekko tag isn't correct. It looks like you are working with the gekko bitcoin trading bot instead of the Gekko Optimization suite: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/